# How to test if screen is started, then execute a command in screen and detach it?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

```
screen -list
There are screens on:
        4278.chat       (07/16/15 14:26:47)     (Detached)
        15127.notifier  (07/16/15 13:27:57)     (Detached)
```

My goal is to :

- **If chat screen is not started then start it, otherwise close it.**
- execute a command in chat session (ex: `node chat.js`)
- detach  chat session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-part answer:

> - If chat screen is not started then start it, otherwise close it.

```
screen -S chat -X quit || screen -S chat
```

Could also `detach` rather than kill the screen session, if that's
what you meant.

> - execute a command in chat session (ex: node chat.js)

If you mean to start a new screen and execute a command, then

```
screen -dm -S chat && screen -S chat -X stuff 'command-to-execute-in-screen-subshell
'
```

Note the embedded new-line inside the quotes.  If the screen is already running, you can leave off the first half.

> - detach chat session

```
screen -S chat -X detach
```

see also answer to first question.

All of this is reasonably documented in the manual.