# ssh, screen, run command and detach in one go?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I like to start a server (basically a `jupiter-notebook`) in a screen session within an SSH, let it run and then detach immediately. doing it one by one:

```
ssh USER@HOST
screen -d -m /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip HOST --port 8889 --no-browser
```

then detach from screen and finally disconnect from SSH. Then use the server. Everything works in this case. One can also see that the screen is running by

```
ssh -t USER@HOST screen -ls
```

Now how do I do the former in one go?

```
ssh -t USER@HOST "screen -d -m /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip HOST --port 8889 --no-browser"
```

does not work. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close, but you don't need the TTY for screen to startup - it creates it's own PTY.  But you do need to put the ssh session in the background allowing the screen process to continue running, as in:

```
ssh -f USER@HOST 'screen -dm command'
```

Might also see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/942961/how-to-test-if-screen-is-started-then-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach-it/943462#943462) for other things you can do to the running screen session if you name it.